# How to disable the Debugger From Breaking On A Task Exception In VS2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Whenever I try to utilize Tasks That Throw Exceptions, usually in the cases of cancelling tasks, the debugger will always break on the exception inside the task delegate not letting me continue without totally removing the exception all together(Even if I wrap a cancelled task inside a try/catch the debugger will still throw on the Cancellation method as it throws an exception). Is there any way to disable this feature as I have to constantly run my programs without a debugger to avoid this feature?

Picture Of Problem:
[image: Debugger Breaking On Exception That Should Be Ignored]

More Info: I am using C# .net core 3.1, vs2019 16.7.2 Community Edition

Comment: Disable breaking on user handled exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways, if you are already debugging:

1. Click the arrow to the left of the exception settings
2. un-check "Break when this exception type is user-unhandled".

If you want to add a global exception to visual studio 2019

Go to Debug > Exceptions dialog, click Add, select Common Language Runtime exceptions, and enter the full name (not the assembly-qualified name) of the exception. Then uncheck the Thrown checkbox for this exception.

﻿